# How to block applications from using SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, block, firewall, tunnel

I am using Little Snitch to control my local applications' internet connection. But when I am at the University, I have to tunnel via ssh to a network-server in order to get an internet connection there.

The problem: If I do so, Little Snitch is not able to control my applications anymore, because then every application uses my ssh tunnel. What's the best way to handle that? Should I block ports on my ssh or is Little Snitch able to manage this?

I am using a Mac and open the ssh connection over the terminal with the following line:

```
ssh -D 2001 -o ServerAliveInterval=60 username@servername.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use mac [MacProxy](http://www.tidalpool.ca/macproxy/) and for Windows [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/) are easiest solutions with more benefits. in addition to blocking any program from connecting to your SSH Tunnel you can also set direct access to your internet for some other programs.

Also you can specify ports and/or IPs for each program and lots more...